# Autohide Toolbar only in full screen mode in Cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa

My goal is simple and yet I cannot find a solution in spite of lots of searching.

Basically, when my app is in full-screen (kiosk) mode, I want the toolbar ***only*** to auto-hide, but I want the menu bar hidden.

Apparently this combination is not valid. I've tried:

```
- (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions: (NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions
{
    return (NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen |
        NSApplicationPresentationHideDock |
        NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar |
        NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideToolbar);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
"... fullscreen presentation options must include NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar if NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideToolbar is included"
```

Thing is, I don't want the menu bar displayed at all!

So, I'm presuming this is not possible using the standard presentation options. Any ideas how I might approach implementing this behaviour manually?

I'm thinking along the lines of: detect the mouse position and only show/hide the toolbar when the mouse is at/near the top of the screen.

I'm very new to Cocoa so not sure where I would start to achieve this. Any help much appreciated!

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 2):

I've got It to work, but only by using private APIs.

First I had to find out how to prevent the menubar from appearing. I discovered the functions `_HIMenuBarPositionLock` and `_HIMenuBarPositionUnlock`, from Carbon (link the app with Carbon.framework).

Then I had to create a custom subclass of NSToolbar, at `awakeFromNib` I register notification observers to lock and unlock the menubar when the window enters and exits fullscreen, respectively:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification object:[self _window] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        // lock menubar position when entering fullscreen so It doesn't appear when the mouse is at the top of the screen
        _HIMenuBarPositionLock();
    }];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSWindowWillExitFullScreenNotification object:[self _window] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        // unlock menubar position when exiting fullscreen
        _HIMenuBarPositionUnlock();
    }];

    [self _setupToolbarHotspotTrackingView];
}
```

`_setupToolbarHotspotTrackingView` is a method on `SOToolbar` which adds a view to the window, this view will be used to track the mouse location and show/hide the toolbar accordingly.

```
- (void)_setupToolbarHotspotTrackingView
{
    NSView *contentView = [self _window].contentView;

    self.toolbarHotspotTrackingView = [[SOToolbarTrackingView alloc] initWithFrame:contentView.bounds];
    [contentView addSubview:self.toolbarHotspotTrackingView];
    self.toolbarHotspotTrackingView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable;
    self.toolbarHotspotTrackingView.toolbar = self;
}
```

I also had to override `_attachesToMenuBar` on `SOToolbar` so the animation works properly.

```
- (BOOL)_attachesToMenuBar
{
    return NO;
}
```

`SOToolbarTrackingView` sets up a tracking area for mouse moved events and checks to see if the mouse is at the top of the window. It then calls some methods on the private class `NSToolbarFullScreenWindowManager` to show and hide the toolbar.

There's too much stuff to explain It all in detail here, I've uploaded my experimental project so you can take a look. [Download the sample project here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Toolbar%20Autohide.zip).